# Solving integral that contain exponential function and lower incomplete gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-function, gamma-function

I have the following integral;

$$y=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-xf}}{m+x}\gamma(a,hx)~dx$$ 
where $f,m,h\in\mathbb{R}^+$ , $a\in\mathbb{N}$ , $\gamma\left(a,h x\right)$ is the lower incomplete gamma function

Can anyone help me how to solve it?

Thank you very much

Comment: This integral doesn't seem convergent. Are you sure that $f>0$?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yes, $f>0$.

I think I found the clue, if we represent the lower incomplete gamma function by infinite sum as the following (by using http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7.E3 ):


$$\gamma(a,h x) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (h x)^{n+a}}{n! (n+a)}
$$

the above equation is true for the case of $a \ne 0, -1, -2, \ldots $ which is valid for my equation.

I think after this the integral can be solved, what do you think?

Comment: You have, as $x \rightarrow +\infty$, $$\gamma(a,hx) = \Gamma(a,0)-x^{a-1}e^{-hx}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{a-2}e^{-hx}\right). $$
Since $\Gamma(a,0) \neq 0$, you get 
$$
\frac{e^{x f}}{m+x}\gamma(a,hx) \sim \Gamma(a,0)\frac{e^{f x}}{x}
$$
as $x \rightarrow +\infty$, giving a **divergent** integral due to $f>0$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I am so sorry, I made a mistake, I forgot to write (-) in front of the (x f).

Comment: @OlivierOloa Do you think my representation is correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it is a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Finding a closed form for this integral seems difficult.

Let us try to obtain an analytic expression.

We may start to write
$$
\begin{align}
y & =\int_{0}^{m}\frac{e^{- x f}}{m+x}\gamma\left(a,h x\right) dx +\int_{m}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{- x f}}{m+x}\gamma\left(a,h x\right) dx 
\\\\ & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{m^k}\!\!\int_{0}^{m}\!\!x^ke^{-f x}\gamma\left(a,h x\right) dx +m^k\!\!\int_{m}^{+\infty}\!\!x^{-k}e^{-f x}\gamma\left(a,h x\right) dx\right)
\end{align}
$$ and then inserting the series expansion you gave in your comment for $\gamma\left(a,h x\right)$.

We will end up with a double series.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xf}}{m+x}\gamma(a,hx)~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-fx}}{x+m}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nh^{n+a}x^{n+a}}{n!(n+a)}dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nh^{n+a}x^{n+a}e^{-fx}}{n!(n+a)(x+m)}dx$

$=\int_m^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nh^{n+a}(x-m)^{n+a}e^{-f(x-m)}}{n!(n+a)x}d(x-m)$

$=\int_m^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nh^{n+a}e^{fm}(x-m)^{n+a}e^{-fx}}{n!(n+a)x}dx$

$=\int_m^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n+a}\dfrac{(-1)^nh^{n+a}e^{fm}C_p^{n+a}(-1)^{n+a-p}m^{n+a-p}x^pe^{-fx}}{n!(n+a)x}dx$

$=\int_m^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n+a}\dfrac{(-1)^{p+a}(n+a-1)!h^{n+a}m^{n+a-p}e^{fm}x^{p-1}e^{-fx}}{n!p!(n+a-p)!}dx$